# update code of angularjs is not working while updating user information" bit" to true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angularjs update code is not working, this error occurs status code

> : function(c){a||(a=vc(b));return c?a[M(c)]||null:a}

```
$scope.Update = function (alumni) {
    var obj = {
        "bit": true
    };
    console.log(obj);

    var onSuccess = function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.result = data;
        swal({
            text: "Registration successful!",
            icon: "success",
            buttons: { ok: true }
        }).then(val => {
            if (val) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    };
    var onerror = function (data, header, status, config) {
        swal("error in approving users!, status code : " + status);
    }

    var promise = $http.put('/api/Examples/' + obj);
    promise.success(onsuccess);
    promise.error(onerror);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting only this error : function(c){a||(a=vc(b));return c?a[M(c)]||null:a} ? Can you please provide full error you are getting in console ? And how update function is getting called ? Is first console is getting printed ?

Comment: no not in console,  i am doing my web project using bootstrap, mvc + webapi with angularjs in visual studio

Comment: okay . You must be running your project and is it running properly in browser? Also can you please answer all the questions in previous comment which will help me to know your exact issue ?